# sending data to bulk out pipe for prolific 2305 always immediately stalls

Tags: c++, macos, usb

i'm trying to connect an old printer with Centronics interface to my Mac running OS X via a USB-to-IEEE1284 adapter containing a Prolific 2305 IC. I closely follow the example at [Apple:USBDevInterfaces](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/USBBook/USBDeviceInterfaces/USBDevInterfaces.html) using IOKit and CF "classes". I find the device, successfully select the only configuration, find the only interface, get printer status byte, open Bulk Out Pipe #1 all successfully, but when i write a single byte to the bulk out pipe it always returns with Pipe stalled error. (I actually have 2 printers and 2 interfaces for testing, the printers behave identically but i excluded one interface from testing because it even stalled on reading the printer status byte.)

Q: Is there something more required to setup for a printing device than shown in the Apple example, e.g. for negotiating the port mode on the centronics interface?

is there a better way for doing this? Unluckily there is no /dev/lp* created for the parallel port.

Here are the most relevant parts from my source. In case more code is needed please ask or see [UsbDevice.cpp](http://k1.spdns.de/Develop/Projects/zxsp-osx/Source/Mac/UsbDevice.cpp) (which contains some more superfluous stuff for my testing and understanding and the procedures below in reverse order.)

Thanks for help.

```
void testProlific2305()
{
    // get device(s)

    CFMutableDictionaryRef dict = newMatchingDictForService(service_USBDevice);
    add(dict,key_VendorID,_prolific);
    add(dict,key_ProductID,_ieee1284);

    io_iterator_t iter = newIteratorForMatchingServices(dict);

    // loop over all devices:

    for(io_service_t device; (device = IOIteratorNext(iter)); IOObjectRelease(device))
    {
        cstr r = testProlific2305device(device);
        if(r) LogLine("%s",r);
    }

    IOObjectRelease(iter);
}

cstr testProlific2305device(io_service_t device)
{
    // note: general error codes in IOReturn.h
    // usb error codes in USB.h line 360ff
    IOReturn err;

    // configure device to use configuration[0]:

    MyIOUSBDeviceInterface** dev_if = newUSBDeviceInterfaceForDevice(device);
    if(!dev_if) return "dev_if = NULL";

    err = (*dev_if)->USBDeviceOpen(dev_if);
    if(err) return usingstr("USBDeviceOpen: error 0x%08X",(uint)err);

    err = ConfigureDevice(dev_if, 0/*configuration_idx*/);
    if(err) return usingstr("ConfigureDevice: error 0x%08X",(uint)err);

    // get interface(s):

    IOUSBFindInterfaceRequest request;
    request.bInterfaceClass    = kIOUSBFindInterfaceDontCare;
    request.bInterfaceSubClass = kIOUSBFindInterfaceDontCare;
    request.bInterfaceProtocol = kIOUSBFindInterfaceDontCare;
    request.bAlternateSetting  = kIOUSBFindInterfaceDontCare;

    io_iterator_t iterator;
    err = (*dev_if)->CreateInterfaceIterator(dev_if, &request, &iterator);

    // loop over all interfaces:

    for(io_service_t interface; (interface = IOIteratorNext(iterator)); IOObjectRelease(interface))
    {
        MyIOUSBInterfaceInterface** if_if = newUSBDeviceInterfaceForInterface(interface);
        if(!if_if) return "if_if = NULL";

        cstr r = testProlific2305interface(dev_if,if_if);
        if(r) LogLine("%s",r);
    }

    err = (*dev_if)->USBDeviceClose(dev_if);
    if(err) return usingstr("USBDeviceClose: error 0x%08X",(uint)err);
    //CFRelease(dev_if); dev_if=NULL;

    return NULL;    // ok
}

cstr testProlific2305interface(MyIOUSBDeviceInterface** dev_if, MyIOUSBInterfaceInterface** if_if)
{
    IOReturn err;

    //Get interface class and subclass:    should be 7, 1
    uint8 interfaceClass, interfaceSubClass;
    err = (*if_if)->GetInterfaceClass(if_if, &interfaceClass);
    err = (*if_if)->GetInterfaceSubClass(if_if, &interfaceSubClass);
    LogLine("Interface class %d, subclass %d\n", interfaceClass, interfaceSubClass);

    // open interface:
    err = (*if_if)->USBInterfaceOpen(if_if);
    if(err) return usingstr("USBDeviceOpen returned error 0x%08X", (uint)err);

    // Get the number of endpoints associated with this interface
    uint8 interfaceNumEndpoints;
    err = (*if_if)->GetNumEndpoints(if_if, &interfaceNumEndpoints);
    if(err) return usingstr("GetNumEndpoints returned error 0x%08X", (uint)err);
    LogLine("interfaceNumEndpoints = %u",interfaceNumEndpoints);

    // Access each pipe in turn, starting with the pipe at index 1
    // The pipe at index 0 is the default control pipe and should be
    // accessed using (*usbDevice)->DeviceRequest() instead

    for(int pipeRef = 1; pipeRef <= interfaceNumEndpoints; pipeRef++)
    {
        cstr r = testProlific2305pipe(dev_if,if_if,pipeRef);
        if(r) LogLine("%s",r);
    }

    return NULL; // ok
}

cstr testProlific2305pipe(MyIOUSBDeviceInterface** dev_if, MyIOUSBInterfaceInterface** if_if, int pipe_idx)
{
    uint16    maxPacketSize;
    uint8    direction, number, transferType, interval, status, interface_idx;
    IOReturn err;

    err = (*if_if)->GetPipeProperties(if_if,
                                pipe_idx, &direction,
                                &number, &transferType,
                                &maxPacketSize, &interval);
    if(err) return usingstr("GetPipeProperties(%d) error: 0x%08X", pipe_idx, err);

    LogLine("Pipe %d: direction %s, transferType %s, maxPacketSize %d",
                                pipe_idx,
                                usb_pipe_direction_str(direction),
                                usp_pipe_transfertype_str(transferType),
                                maxPacketSize);

    err = (*if_if)->GetPipeStatus(if_if, pipe_idx);
    if(err) return usingstr("GetPipeStatus error: 0x%08X", (uint)err);

    err = printerGetPortStatus(dev_if, interface_idx, &status);
    if(err) return usingstr("printerGetPortStatus error: 0x%08X",(uint)err);
    if(status!=0x18) LogLine("Printer status = 0x%02X", status); // 0x18 = no error, selected, paper ok

    cstr msg = "0";     // just 1 char
    err = (*if_if)->WritePipe(if_if, pipe_idx, (void*)msg, strlen(msg)); 

// ****-->  Here i always get error: 0xE00002ed device not responding

    if(err)
    {
        LogLine("WritePipe: error 0x%08X", (uint)err);

        err = printerGetPortStatus(dev_if, 0/*interface*/, &status);
        if(err) LogLine("printerGetPortStatus error: 0x%08X",(uint)err);
        return "bulk write to pipe failed";
    }
    return NULL; // ok
}

IOReturn printerGetPortStatus(MyIOUSBDeviceInterface **dev, uint interface_idx, uint8* result)
{
    IOUSBDevRequest request;
    request.bmRequestType = 0b10100001; 
    request.bRequest = 1;              
    request.wValue = 0;
    request.wIndex = interface_idx;
    request.wLength = 1;
    request.pData = result;

    IOReturn err = (*dev)->DeviceRequest(dev, &request);
    XXXASSERT(err || request.wLenDone==1);
    return err;
}

IOReturn ConfigureDevice(MyIOUSBDeviceInterface **dev, uint configuration_idx)
{
    uint8       num_configurations;
    IOReturn    err;
    IOUSBConfigurationDescriptorPtr configuration_descriptor;

    // Get the number of configurations.
    err = (*dev)->GetNumberOfConfigurations(dev, &num_configurations);      XXXASSERT(!err);
    if(configuration_idx >= num_configurations) return error;

    // Get the configuration descriptor
    err = (*dev)->GetConfigurationDescriptorPtr(dev, configuration_idx, &configuration_descriptor);
    if(err) { LogLine("GetConfigurationDescriptorPtr: error = 0x%08X", err); return err; }

    // Set the device’s configuration. The configuration value is found in
    // the bConfigurationValue field of the configuration descriptor
    err = (*dev)->SetConfiguration(dev, configuration_descriptor->bConfigurationValue);
    if(err) { LogLine("SetConfiguration: error = 0x%08X", err); return err; }

    return ok;
}
```

Comment: Have similar problem. I used USB4Java to do communication. pipe can not be opened until I print something with mac utility. Do you have any progress?

Comment: no, i was out of clues and looked for alternate options like building an interface on my own. Your observation may indicate that some kind of initialization is missing. I still don't know.

Comment: I haven't find a solution in USB. I gave up and use CUPS instead. Stock cups works well on Mavericks but Yosemite need usbtb. For me this is a solution for my thermal printer. Hope my repo helps. https://github.com/DeqingSun/XP-T58KC_On_Mac